# How to sort output based on computer name

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I have below script for checking if an application with name "security" in it is installed or not in remote servers. For example i am searching for two servers. I want to sort the output based on server name.

```
PS C:\Users\TEMP.DEBPO\Desktop> Get-WmiObject -computerName USWTODWV01,USWPISMWV01 -Class Win32_Product | sort-object co
mputerName,Name | select SystemName,Name | where { $_.Name -match "security"}

SystemName                                                  Name
----------                                                  ----
                                                            Trend Micro Deep Security Agent
                                                            Trend Micro Deep Security Agent
```

Under system name i want to see computer name. Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a calculated property as an argument to `select`:

```
... | Select @{Name='SystemName';Expression={$_.ComputerName}},Name | ...
```

But you're probably looking for the `__SERVER` property of the WMI instance, rather than `ComputerName`:

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName USWTODWV01,USWPISMWV01 -Class Win32_Product | Sort-Object __SERVER,Name | select @{Name='SystemName';Expr={$_.__SERVER}},Name | where { $_.Name -match "security"}
```